# SAP PI 7.5 XML validation throws errors for upper case Boolean values

Tags: uppercase, xml-validation, sap-pi, sap-xi

We are using a custom validation class for XML validation in ESR. In SAP 7.4 the XML Validation was successful but after PI 7.5 the XML validation fails with this message:

> Validation Exception: Inbound XML Validation against schema failed.

We are particularly facing issue for Boolean Data type. In PI 7.4 the Boolean values was accepted in upper case but in PI 7.5 it throws error.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

Was the "old" PI on 7.4 a dual stack installation? If so, that could be the reason (assuming you didn't use ICO).

xsd:boolean does accept {true, false, 1, 0}. Case matters.

BTW you can disable XML check in communication channel for sender channel and then deal with the "wrong" uppercase values e.g. in message mapping.